# dotnetnuke module development

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5

ok i have a news module in the left panel of my page. To view the details i want to open it in the middle pane.

what i have currently done is to create a new module and make a detail page in it to be opened in the middle pane. Is there any better technique that I can use here in this scenario ? so that I can create a detail page in the **current module** and make it open in the middle pane not in the same pane as it is  . I am using dotnetnuke version 6.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to keep the "list" on the left, or just display the detail in the middle when viewing the contents of the module?

One approach, might be to use the RSS feed from your news module on a Home page, then have your article module itself on another page in the "middle" pane. A user clicks on the RSS from the home page and that would take them to the article/detail page.

Another approach would be to have two modules in your module package, one called Article List, and one called Article display. Article List would build links with something like DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.NavigateURL(TabId, "", "ArticleId="+ArticleId.ToString());

Then your article detail view module would hide itself, unless the Article ID was passed in as a querystring parameter in the URL.

Another approach, would be to have multiple "View" controls within your Module Definition, the first having no "ControlKey" in the definition, making it the default view. Then have a "ControlKey" called Details. Have your list build a link with EditUrl("Details","ArticleId="+ArticleId.ToString();
This would have DNN load the details view, in the Content Pane of the page, but not other modules would load on the page.